# when i start laravel echo server i get error?

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-echo

i am trying to create online chat and first i try to get online users .
i used   predis  ,laravel echo ,yarn  ,socket.io-client and laravel-echo-server.
and this my app.js code :

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'socket.io',
host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
console.log("ok  ");
window.Echo.join('online')
.here((users) => {
    console.log('ok here');
})
.joining((user) => {
    console.log(user.name);
})
.leaving((user) => {
    console.log(user.name);
});
```

my channel :

```
Broadcast::channel('online', function ($user) {
   return $user;
});
```

after run my browser :
 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn12F.png)

laravel echo server :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJXFu.png)

i added `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` in

> config/app.php
> and change **.env** *BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis*

Comment: did you init echo server?

Comment: yes of course @maki10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your echo server is trying to auth against `http://localhost` when your Laravel app is on `http://localhost:8000`

You probably want to set the `authHost` config to `http://localhost:8000` in your `laravel-echo-server.json` config file